# How do I open TCP ports 7080 and 7090 for use with Merlin?

Tags: network

I'm trying to set up Merlin server on my Mac to send a GANTT chart to my iPad. I need to open TCP ports 7080 and 7090 for it to work. What's the best way to open those ports?

Comment: If no one guesses what you are stuck on, you might elaborate by editing the question why you feel the software just doesn't open the ports when you configure and run it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the firewall settings? (Apple menu -> System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Firewall Options...)

There you'll find options to block everything, to permit signed software to open ports to listen, and you can click on the '+' button to add a new application.